# Mongo DB collection from one to another

Tags: database, mongodb

lets say in Mongo DB i have 2 collections (collection1 and collection2). the TTL index of collection 1 is 3 days and collection2 is 60 days. what i want is a job to run daily that copies data of last 24 hrs from collection 1 to 2.

tried to use this but

db.collection1.copyTo("collection2") Deprecated since version 3.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: shell script . i am trying to run it from terminal.

Answer (score 0):

db.collection.aggregate([ { $match:{condition} }, { $out:"new Collection" } ]);